# Sufficient conditions for the convergence of countably infinite products of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm interested in countably infinite products of matrices of the form
$$T_k=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&\cdots &0&0&0\\
0 &\ddots&0&\cdots&0&0\\
a_{i1}& \cdots& a_{ii}&\cdots &a_{i(n-1)}&a_{in}\\
0&0&\cdots&1&0&0\\
\vdots&\cdots&0&0&\ddots&0\\
0&\cdots &0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Given that for each $k$, $T_k$ can be chosen from a set of $n$ different matrices, each one being the identity on all rows except row $i$, where it is given by a vector $\textbf{a}_i$, and assuming that the number of times that each matrix appears in the sequence is infinite, I would like to derive sufficient conditions for the convergence of all such infinite products, $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}T_k$.  What I would like to know, is whether there has been any work done on this type of problem.  Resources/ relevant papers/texts would be a great help.